# Selecting columns based on value given in other column using pandas in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame as:

```
a   b   c   d......

1   1
3   3   3   5
4   1   1   4   6
1   0
```

I want to select number of columns based on value given in column "a". In this case for first row it would only select column b.
How can I achieve something like:

```
df.iloc[:,column b:number of columns corresponding to value in column a]
```

My expected output would be:

```
a   b   c   d   e
1   1   0   0   1     # 'e' contains value in column b because colmn a = 1 
3   3   3   5   335   #  'e' contains values of column b,c,d because colm a 
4   1   1   4   1      #  = 3
1   0           NAN
```

Comment: So, do all the other values have NaNs?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ no! not necessarily. Could be NaNs or some value

Comment: Okay, let me know if my answer isn't what you're looking for (if it is, please vote and accept it, thanks a bunch).

Comment: @coldspeed  and @ tai thanks for the answer but I actually wanted a column, suppose "e" that would contain 1 in first row, 335 in second row,1146 in third and 0 in fourth row

Comment: Can you give your expect output more clearly? You should be able to select from my output easily. You can delete column `a` if you don't need it.

Comment: @Tai I have edited the required output to make it more clear. I hope that helps

Comment: @gokyori Checkout my update. `e` is used. So I put it in `f`. Please consider accepting the answer if this works for you :P Also, I think your output is wrong. `6` is gone. You should have it as `f` column like my result.

Comment: Let me edit my answer before you decide to accept anything.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ please do edit !

Comment: @gokyori Done...

Comment: @gokyori check out my new one-line solution as well :P

Comment: @gokyori You can accept just one answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A numpy slicing approach

```
a = v[:, 0]
b = v[:, 1:]
n, m = b.shape
b = b.ravel()
b = np.where(b == 0, '', b.astype(str))
r = np.arange(n) * m
f = lambda t: b[t[0]:t[1]]

df.assign(g=list(map(''.join, map(f, zip(r, r + a)))))

   a  b  c  d  e     g
0  1  1  0  0  0     1
1  3  3  3  5  0   335
2  4  1  1  4  6  1146
3  1  0  0  0  0
```

Answer (score 3):

Define a little function for this:

```
def select(df, r):
    return df.iloc[r, 1:1 + df.iat[r, 0]]
```

The function uses `iat` to query the `a` column for that row, and `iloc` to select columns from the same row.

Call it as such:

```
select(df, 0)

b    1.0
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```

And,

```
select(df, 1)

b    3.0
c    3.0
d    5.0
Name: 1, dtype: float64
```

---

Based on your edit, consider this -

```
df

   a  b  c  d  e
0  1  1  0  0  0
1  3  3  3  5  0
2  4  1  1  4  6
3  1  0  0  0  0
```

Use `where`/`mask` (with numpy broadcasting) + `agg` here -

```
df['e'] = df.iloc[:, 1:]\
            .astype(str)\
            .where(np.arange(df.shape[1] - 1) < df.a[:, None], '')\
            .agg(''.join, axis=1)

df

   a  b  c  d     e
0  1  1  0  0     1
1  3  3  3  5   335
2  4  1  1  4  1146
3  1  0  0  0     0
```

If nothing matches, then those entries in `e` will have an empty string. Just use `replace` -

```
df['e'] = df['e'].replace('', np.nan)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: one line solution with slicing.

```
df["f"] = df.astype(str).apply(lambda r: "".join(r[1:int(r["a"])+1]), axis=1)

# df["f"] = df["f"].astype(int)  if you need `f` to be integer

df    
    a   b   c   d   e   f
0   1   1   X   X   X   1
1   3   3   3   5   X   335
2   4   1   1   4   6   1146
3   1   0   X   X   X   0
```

Dataset used:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': {0: 1, 1: 3, 2: 4, 3: 1},
                   'b': {0: 1, 1: 3, 2: 1, 3: 0},
                   'c': {0: 'X', 1: '3', 2: '1', 3: 'X'},
                   'd': {0: 'X', 1: '5', 2: '4', 3: 'X'},
                   'e': {0: 'X', 1: 'X', 2: '6', 3: 'X'}})
```

Suggestion for improvement would be appreciated!

Comment: Thankyou very much, this approach is very much useful for this particular problem. could you please suggest me a way to do the similar operation if column "a" was in different dataframe? I should have asked it as a different question though.

Comment: That should be easy @gokyori Just change the lambda function a bit. `r.name` can help you get the index and you can use the index to access values in other df. @gokyori

Comment: @gokyori I am not fully aware about the structure of your new problem. One way is to temporarily add the column to this df. Another is to use the `r.name` method I mentioned above. You can tag me in your new question if you want.